# Javascript function that check if the browser is loading a webpage (Firefox Extension)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox Extension and I need a JS/AJAX function that checks if a webpage is loading in the browser. I already tried this:

```
while(!document.getElementById(webpageElementId)){};
```

but this turn into an infinite loop and Firefox just freeze. I need a script/loop that is checking if the webpage is loading without freezing the Firefox window, and letting the webpage load.

I searched almost everywhere and didn't find anything useful.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [*Web Progress Listeners*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events#Web_progress_listeners).